# Scala and SparkSQL: ClassNotPersistableException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datanucleus

I am trying to create two dataframe and join it using dataframe.join method.

Here is scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object RuleExecutor {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(AppConstants.AppName).setMaster("local")
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName(AppConstants.AppName).config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    import sparkSession.sql

    sql(s"CREATE DATABASE test")

    sql ("CREATE TABLE test.box_width (id INT, width INT)")   // Create table box_width
    sql ("INSERT INTO test.box_width VALUES (1,1), (2,2)")    // Insert data in box_width

    sql ("CREATE TABLE test.box_length (id INT, length INT)") // Create table box_length
    sql ("INSERT INTO test.box_length VALUES (1,10), (2,20)") // Insert data in box_length

    val widthDF = sql("select *  from  test.box_width")       // Get DF for table box_width
    val lengthDF = sql("select *  from  test.box_length")     // Get DF for table box_length

    val dimensionDF = lengthDF.join(widthDF, "id");           // Joining
    dimensionDF.show();
  }
}
```

But when running code, I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1062)…..
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)……
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)……
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)……
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)…
Caused by: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MVersionTable" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MVersionTable" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:473)……
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MVersionTable" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.assertClassPersistable(ExecutionContextImpl.java:5113)……
```

Versions that I am using are

Scala = 2.11 
Spark-hive = 2.2.2 
Maven-org-spark-project-hive_hive-metastore = 1.x 
DataNucleus = 5.x

How to resolve this issue? [complete log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BT7Rw3B-vVX6nbx51Oyj25BlJACI7hYq/view?usp=sharing)
[list of dependencies](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14Hq9pfyk9xljqpVYhQqipZfdo0rTHBydYsG_BdJMAR0/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Comment: `ClassNotPersistableException: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MVersionTable" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.`. It tells you what is wrong. Perhaps process that information, such as enhancing that class, or making it visible in the CLASSPATH

Comment: @BillyFrost Thanks for reply Billy. Actually I am not able to understand what "enhancing" actually means? Regarding class visibility in classpath, I can see datanucleus jars in classpath argument when IDE is invoking run. Is anything else need to be checked?

Comment: well you claim to be using DataNucleus, and its documentation tells you what enhancing is ... any class you persist has to be enhanced

Comment: @BillyFrost is there any way so that I can still use derby embedded hive metastore without using DataNucleus?

Comment: Huh? DataNucleus ALLOWS you to use WHICHEVER database you want to use for persistence. The problem is not the database, or DataNucleus. More likely how you have configured whatever software you are actually using

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to use `;` at the end of lines anymore, unless you have more than one expression in one line while writing Scala code.

Second, I went through your log, and there are 15 errors, mainly either the database table is not there or can't find hive. So I think these instances are not running correctly. Could you make sure you have all those things (Hive, MySql DB) setup correctly, before running the spark job?

Comment: Thanks Seyed. I am new in spark domain. You have rightly pointed out that I haven't set Hive or any DBMS. I forgot to mention in question post that I was running code like "java -cp ....jar". After running code from spark-shell, I am able to run the code successfully. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: @user811602 that’s great. Congrats! Glad I could help.

Comment: It seems I don't need to set Mysql, as in standalone mode. While running code through IDE - IntelliJ, embedded Derby database is used. I am still getting same exception from IDE. As It is only for development, I don't want to setup database like Mysql for same. Is there way out so that I can make it workable with default embedded database (derby) only?