# Datanucleus Enhancer: IntelliJ: Plugin issue

Tags: intellij-idea, datanucleus

I have create project with dependency :

```
        Spark-hive = 2.2.1;
        Kryo = 4.0; #Needed for serialization
        J2ee_servlet = 3.1;
        Maven-org-spark-project-hive_hive-metastore = 1.x;
        DataNucleus = 5.x;
```

While executing code: I am getting error:

> Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException:
>   The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MVersionTable" is
>   not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or
>   that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is
>   hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the
>   class are not found.

[Complete question/log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628227/scala-and-sparksql-classnotpersistableexception)

To solve this, I have added plugin "DataNucleus Enhancer integration" in IntelliJ IDE and added jar "datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar" as external dependency also.

Even after doing this, I am NOT able to find any IntelliJ UI component to enable Datanucleus enhancer in my project. [DataNucleus documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/guides/idea/index.html#preferences)
for same is not updated.

```
IntelliJ Version: IntelliJ IDEA COMMUNITY 2018.1
Plugin "DataNucleus Enhancer integration": 1.1.0-beta1
Scala: 2.11
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
```

How to enable Datanucleus Enhancer for my project?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using "DataNucleus 5.x" why would you use "datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar" ? Would have thought the best way to enhance would be via the Maven / Ant routes. This "Enhancer integration" and the link you point to was never part of the DataNucleus project from what I see, and the person who wrote it went silent long ago

Comment: Yes, I tried without adding it but get same output. As per plugin doc: "The datanucleus enhancer is not packaged with this plugin, but it's, by default, taken from (each) project module to avoid version conflicts", so added it in case it works.

Comment: I am now trying to add real time enhancer:     
val enhancer: JDOEnhancer = JDOHelper.getEnhancer()
enhancer.setVerbose(true)
enhancer.enhance()

Is there anyway i can tell enhancer to enhance particular class like "enhancer.enhanceClass(org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MVersionTable)"

Comment: @BillyFrost reason why I am not using ANT/MAVEN is that, in that case I need to build whole project again and again to test change, but for faster development, I just wanted to run code from IDE. Addition to this, in industry, we are using different internal package management tool system(MAVEN is not used)

Comment: `JDOEnhancer` has many methods to define what to enhance ... http://www.datanucleus.org/javadocs/javax.jdo/3.2/javax/jdo/JDOEnhancer.html#addClasses-java.lang.String...-   and you might want to just "run code" but that doesnt allow for post-compile steps